# OpenGL ES 2.0 renders coloured screen without the images

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to render sprites using OpenGL ES 2.0. However I only get a coloured screen without the sprites. Everything is setup correctly as far as I see. What could be wrong? Here is how I setup the projection and view matrices:

```
    this.position = new Vector2(frustumWidth/2, frustumHeight/2);

    for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
        mtrxProjection[i] = 0.0f;
        mtrxView[i] = 0.0f;
        mtrxProjectionAndView[i] = 0.0f;
    }       
    Matrix.orthoM(mtrxProjection, 0, position.x - frustumWidth * zoom / 2, 
                                     position.x + frustumWidth * zoom / 2,
                                     position.y - frustumHeight * zoom / 2,
                                     position.y + frustumHeight * zoom / 2,
                                     10 , -10 );
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mtrxView, 0, position.x, position.y, 0.0f, position.x, position.y, -1.0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mtrxProjectionAndView, 0, mtrxProjection, 0, mtrxView, 0);
```

Comment: Which language? What sprites? Are the textures missing? Did you set up the shader correctly? What makes you suspect the projection? There is a lot that can go wrong outside the projection setup....

Comment: Here it is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26511732/simple-sprite-render-in-opengl-es-2-0-renders-coloured-screen-without-the-images

Comment: Did you actually duplicate your question?

Comment: what are image dimensions? are images in POT dimension?